# What is the function signature of app.render, how is app.render used in the Next.js example files?

Tags: express, next.js

I have a Next.js app with an Express server in `server.js` (using custom server deployment.)

In the Next.js example `server.js` file, `app.render(req, res, '/a', req.query);` is used.

I understand that `res.render` uses `app.render` and that `app.render` is used for serving 'raw' content by means other than the HTTP protocol.

The Express docs detail that `app.render` takes the arguments:

`app.render(view, [locals], callback)`

So in the the Next.js example files, `app.render(req, res, '/a', req.query);`

req=view,

res=locals,

'/a'=locals,

req.query=callback

I'm struggling to make sense of the use of `app.render` here, and the arguments passed to it.

What are the arguments passed here, and how do they correlate with the documented express function signature?

As a supplementary question -

Next.js docs define this pattern as: `This is obviously a non-standard routing strategy.`

In what way is it non-standard, and why not use a standard routing pattern for example purposes?

Comment: Express' `app.render` is different from [Next.js' `app.render`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/55e4a3d1add44aede18f4bc9f604f59ba49cc0b0/packages/next/next-server/server/next-server.ts#L1206), which is the one used in the example.

Comment: That explains half the issue  - Any idea where docs are for the Next.js version?

Comment: It's not documented outside the source code, as far as I'm aware.